# OpenShift Node REST Service error "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: openshift

I have a REST service written in Node using Restify that works running on my host system, and works if I'm ssh'd into the cartridge.  But when I try to call this service remotely, the service cannot be reached (on a browser I get a "This site can’t be reached" error).

I'm actually running two applications at the same time. One is an express app that serves dynamic web pages using Express, and calls the REST service that is running on another port.

The web page works fine except for when it tries to access the REST service.  It is using the configured OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP port.  The REST service is using a port I've specified: 8097.

For a simple test, I've created a rest endpoint that responds with simple status.  While in an SSH session on the cartridge, I can type this and see this result:

```
curl http://${NODE_IP}:8097/status
"{status: 'ok'}"
```

But on my host system, I cannot curl this address using the public ip address assigned to the cartridge:

```
curl 52.87.189.180:8097/status
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 52.87.189.180 port 8097: Operation timed out
```

I am able to curl the web application and get through:

```
curl 52.87.189.180
```

I read somewhere about HA Proxy being an issue for web-balanced applications, but I don't have that right now.  My application is a simple NodeJS cartridge along with MongoDB.  The REST Server functions correctly locally, is enabled for CORS, and uses the OpenShift environment variables to configure connectivity.  Here are the ports:

```
lsof -l
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE     SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mongod  22936     3389   11u  IPv4  518405103  0t0      TCP  127.6.158.130:27017 (LISTEN)
node    23028     3389   11u  IPv4  518408054  0t0      TCP  127.6.158.129:8097 (LISTEN)
node    23028     3389   12u  IPv4  518408056  0t0      TCP  127.6.158.129:8080 (LISTEN)
```

So my question is, what could be stopping me from accessing the rest application from the outside world?

**Edit 2/1/2017:**

This is interesting.  I looked up port forwarding and tried this from my host system:

```
rhc port-forward -a myappname
```

Now I am able locally to connect to my REST service on http://localhost:8097.  My curl commands above work when substituting localhost for the remote ip address, and I can use a REST client (I'm using Postman) to test my endpoints.

There must be some sort of firewall rule blocking external access, or maybe its something to do with the way I've set up the response headers in the REST application itself.  If the latter were the case, I would think there would be some sort of response with an error code included, not a timeout waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not seeing any responses as to how this can be done the OpenShift way, I figured out how to do this programmatically.  See my [solution](https://github.com/scottellis64/openshift-proxy-sample) on Github.